# Recursively iterating over documentfragment nodes and all child nodes

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

I'm parsing an html string via `createContextualFragment` :

```
let DocumentFragmentDom = IframeDocument.createRange().createContextualFragment(this.Html);
```

And i'm trying to append each node separately to my ifame like this:

```
while(DocumentFragmentDom.children.length > 0) {
   if(DocumentFragmentDom.children[0].nodeName.toLowerCase() === "script" &&
      DocumentFragmentDom.children[0].hasAttribute("src"))
   {
      DocumentFragmentDom.children[0].addEventListener("load",RecursiveAppending.bind(this));
      IframeDocument.body.appendChild(DocumentFragmentDom.children[0]);
      return;
    }
    IframeDocument.body.appendChild(DocumentFragmentDom.children[0]);
}
```

you can see that if the node is a script tag with the `src` attribute i will add an `eventlistener` for the load event, and the callback is the same function, the reason i'm doing this is because if i have got in my html code 2 script tags , one is using external resource and the other is inline , if i will not wait for the load event for the external tag the inline will run before it even if the inline tag is below the external.

With this code everything is working perfectly but I would like to be able to append individual nodes and when the node has `children`, I would like to append the parent node first and than each children and if the `children` have `children` I would like to continue doing this.

I also need to take in consideration the `eventlistener` for the script tag because if i encounter a script tag with `src` I need to use a callback and stop appending until the event is fired and than I need to continue in the exact same point.
one more thing to consider is when you append a node from `documentfragment` to another document the node will be moved from the `documentfragment` to the new document so I'm not sure how exactly I should do that, maybe clone each node?

Comment: Appending a node to a different location takes its children with it. If you wanted to avoid that and still use the original node and not a clone/newly created one, then you would have to move those children out of the node first.

Comment: @CBroe where should i store them? and still how should i do the recursive function?

Comment: You can either move them into a different parent, or use removeChild, which will returned the removed node, so that you could push it into an array or something.

Comment: @CBroe so yes i can use removeChild on the parent node and store it in a variable and than how should i proceed ? if the childrens have childrens? how should i wait until i append them and how should i continue to append from where i left of?

Comment: I don’t know, this seems pretty much an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) right now to me … A more specific description/concrete example of what actual problem you are trying to solve here might help perhaps.

Comment: @CBroe i have described the problem above , i need to be able to parse each node separately because if i will append a node with several script tags as children an if i will not append the js tags in the correct order and wait for tags with src to load than i will get an error, so i need to be able to append each node separately and recursively if the node has childrens

Comment: Well I think instead of removing nodes from your original document, you might indeed be better off with cloning nodes individually here (shallow clone, not including the children.) That way, the structure of your original will be preserved, so that you can loop over/recursively dive into that.

Comment: @CBroe that's a great idea but i need something to start with because i don't quite understand how to implement this